# htaccess to redirect all referrers except one

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying to write an htaccess file for awhile now with no luck.

so I need to redirect everyone away from my site unless they are coming from a specific URL.

So only if the referrer is from lets say www.yahoo.com will it go through otherwise it will get redirected.

It needs to match the root domain so if the referrer is www.yahoo.com/somedirectory
or
www.yahoo.com/?someparam=someparamvalue&etcetc=etcetc

it should get passed through and NOT redirected.

Could anyone help me please.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://www\.yahoo\.com/
RewriteRule ^ /wrong-referer-url? [L,R]
```

Comment: That should do it. Thank you!